# Asynchronous, Thread-Safe Collection Implementing INotifyCollectionChanged

Tags: c#, silverlight, task-parallel-library

I am using Silverlight 5.0 and need to implement `IList<T>` and IList.  My collection is going to be used to add and remove items from it's inner collection constantly, and the UI will have elements bound to the collection.  For performance reasons, I don't want the UI to render everytime the collection changes, as, I want a "group" of changes to be made to the collection, and then raise the collection changed event.  I also want to be able to do this using the Task.Factory approach to keep everything asynchronous.  Has anyone seen any good examples of how to achieve this?

Comment: Caliburn Micro has a Bindable Collection with a property of IsNotifying which can be turned off and on. I have not used it in a multithreaded mutexed environment. But, it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

A thread-safe, observable collection is problematic by design. For example, if you change the collection, and that raises the event, while that event is being handled the collection could be changed on another thread. As a result, the handler that was just told an item was added could already be out of date (the item could be gone already).

Alternatively, have you considered using an [immutable collection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/12/18/preview-of-immutable-collections-released-on-nuget.aspx) with an event when the collection changes? It is intrinsically thread-safe and would not suffer from the above design-problem if you apply it correctly. It may not fit your requirements for this app -- it's hard to tell from the question.

Comment: The fact that the handler may called after it is out of date should not be considered a problem.  It's not hard for a handler to deal with such things, and there's no reason a decently-written handler shouldn't be prepared for them.  A bigger issue is that something may be added to the collection while an event handler is already running.  Normally, code which calls `SomeCollection.Add` would be entitled to assume that all event handlers will have fired before it returns, but imposing such semantics would create the possibility of deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would suggest would be to have various flags for different aspects of the collection for which the UI may need to be updated.  If something in the collection changes and a particular flag isn't set, set it and use `Control.BeginInvoke` on a supplied control and delegate (use either `Interlocked` or locks to ensure that the flag test-and-set is done in thread-safe fashion).  The UI update method should test and clear the appropriate flags before performing its updates; if any updates were performed, the method should loop and re-test all the flags until it completes without having to perform any updates.

Using this approach, one should be able to avoid having an excessive number of pending operations enqueued via `BeginUpdate`.  There may be some redundant updates, but generally not too many.  In some cases, it may be helpful to have the control's code limit the number of updates it will perform per second; if the update routine would cycle through too many times, start a timer and disable updates until the timer expires.  If the timer expires and updates are needed, perform the updates and restart the timer; if it expires and no updates are needed, kill the timer.

Trying to have every single change to the collection be reflected in "update" events is apt to be counterproductive.  Simply make certain that the last update to the display happens entirely after the last change to the collection.